# How to get user mail picture from exchange Web services

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I’m trying to get AD user picture through Exchange Serve web services. But when I  run the code to the server it returns me the following error:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

Credential to my mail box are correctly!

```
HttpWebRequest request =

                WebRequest.Create("https://www.contoso.com/ews/exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=sadie@contoso.com&size=HR240x240";)

                as HttpWebRequest;

                CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();

                cc.Add(

                new Uri("https://www.contoso.com/ews/exchange.asmx/s/GetUserPhoto?email=sadie@contoso.com&size=HR240x240";), 

                "NTLM", 

                new NetworkCredential("domainusername", "Mypass"));

                request.Credentials = cc;

                         request.Credentials =cc;

                // Submit the request.

                using (HttpWebResponse resp = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)

                {

                    // Take the response and save it as an image.

                    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(resp.GetResponseStream());

                    image.Save("Sadie.jpg");

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

What if you try:

```
new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")
```

And make sure the URI is the correct one (**not www.contoso.com**).

Comment: If I try https://www.contoso.com/ews/exchange.asmx/ on the browser, it returns me the Exchange WSDL. So I think it's ok. Otherwise it would not return me Access denied.  But I'm not quite sure about the method I found on MSDN  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj190905%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx#bk_EWS

Comment: Do this first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj900154(v=exchg.150).aspx